# VLC Playlist loop on Raspberry startup

Tags: boot, video, vlc

I am trying to create the simplest digital signage, so I thought I could create a VLC playlist and then play it on system startup on fullscreen and with hidden cursor.
I've read about the paid alternatives and such but it is something I don't want to invest in, yet.
So, my question is, if anyone has been in this situation and if you think it is possible to do it this way.

Comment: Personally I would probably use omxplayer, the omxplayer-wrapper and some Python code. https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Other options 'Pi Presents' https://pipresents.wordpress.com or 'Raspberry Digital Signage' https://www.binaryemotions.com/digital-signage/raspberry-digital-signage/

Comment: Alright @CoderMike , I've read about most of these and I tried the pipresents one but it was ok I guess, I will continue my research based on your comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this same problem as well. You can run the command line version of VLC and point it to your playlist and it should work:

https://github.com/bobburgers7/pi-video-photo-slideshow